# Why do we need function definition before calling it in C++?

Tags: c++

Hello to all I am new to C++ language and I came across with interesting fact that we cannot call function before defining it. I have searched on stackoverflow but couldn't find proper answer. I am thinking why just declarations are not enough to call a function because linker  can check the parameter list from declarations. Let me give an example to clarify:

We have one example.cpp file and we have function log(char* message) and we have just declared it(not define) then if we try to call this function like log("hello world") it will give error. I know that we don't necessarily need to define it in the same file( because linker can link it at the link time). However I don't understand why we even need to define?

Comment: You don't need a *definition* - just a *declaration* before calling will be sufficient. But you will need a definition *somewhere* in the code, at link time.

Comment: Maybe if you had an example of this we can help with your confusion because @AdrianMole is correct.

Comment: Where did you come accross this 'fact'? Can you give a link? The fact is wrong of course.

Comment: If the fact was true, then recursive functions (certainly mutually recursive functions) would be impossible.

Comment: C++ is stricter than C with type checking, including the types of functions. This is good for finding programming errors early (during compile time as opposed to during link time or run time).In C++ it is also needed for proper overload resolution (argument to parameter matching). In C you *could* call an undeclared function. The compiler would simply generate code to pass the arguments you provided, and for an int return value. C++ forbids this because calling a function the wrong way will lead to errors which may be hard to find.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Please post a [mcve], which would include all of the code needed to reproduce the problem, and full unedited compiler messages.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based upon a false claim. The question should be reformulated to focus on the basis of that claim.

Comment: the question is quite clear. My question was why linker needs definition of functions instead declerations could be enough.

Comment: "My question was why linker needs definition of functions". It certainly didn't sound this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer**: You *don't* need a function definition to compile your code, but you *do* need a function definition to link it (and execute it of course!).

Some clarifications, trying to keep things simple:

- The declaration of a function is what it takes, what it returns
- The definition of a function is its content

#### Compiling

The compiler can compile code that is calling a function (e.g. `std::cout`), and only having its declaration. The compiler will just check that the way you call this function is compatible with its declaration. This is what is done every time you `#include <>` and use something from the standard library.

#### Linking

During the linking phase (linking your call to the actual compiled function content), the linker will have your code jump to the *compiled definition* of this target function. So at this point, you either need the object file with the compiled version of the function (if part of the same compilation target), or the library which already contains the compiled definition.

This is why you can include headers (e.g. `#include <string>`), containing the *declaration*, use the symbols defined in there, and compile your code. But when linked, it will need the *definition*, either provided by you or a library. If you don't, you will see a linker error, typically `Undefined symbol <xxx>`, which means it couldn't find the definition, and wasn't able to have your code jump to whatever you want it to do.

Comment: Not sure about the word "signature"; the return type is normally not considered to be a part of it. I'd also mention that (almost?) all definitions are also declarations.

Comment: Right, trying to make this easy to grasp, not necessarily adhering to the exact standard wording... combining both is challenging :D. Open to suggestions.

Comment: thank you this is what I mean. i made a mistake by saying compiler rather than linker. But still I dont understand why linker needs it

Comment: The linker will need the definition of a function you called.

Comment: @subhanceo A C++ application is compiled as you know, and the output is architecture-specific machine code. That code contains all operations in a way the CPU can understand. And the CPU won't understand something like "read this file and run that as a function". What it will understand however is "jump at address 0x7ae89413 and execute the instructions that are there". And this means obviously that instructions (compiled definition) and the address of where these are must be available to generate this "jump" code.

Comment: Note that if linking to a dynamic library (.dll, .so) specifically, however (not your code, not a static library), you don't need (and won't have) the definitions when compiling your executable. Instead the OS is going to basically define the correct jump when you run your application, i.e. not at compile time.